# How to ensure that two foreign keys both belong to the same user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following (simplified) database model, where I refer to users of the application as "teacher":

```
class Student(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name="students")
    name = models.TextField()

class Task(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name="tasks")
    description = models.TextField()

class Grade(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grade =  models.FloatField()
```

How do I ensure that the grade belongs only to one `teacher`? Or is there another way to improve my model?

Thanks

**edit:**
I just found another SO question that answers a similar question:
[In django, how to limit choices of a foreignfield based on another field in the same model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123294/in-django-how-to-limit-choices-of-a-foreignfield-based-on-another-field-in-the)

Am I right, that I "have to ensure it at the input"?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Django Smart Selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) we use them in our project to solve that exact problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find a workaround with unique_together (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) by overriding it for your special needs.

But it might not be easy: [Django Unique Together (with foreign keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440010/django-unique-together-with-foreign-keys)

But it's never wrong to check values before insert ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe teacher should be a separate class, and teacher in Task class should be related with teacher from Student class. Maybe usage the [through argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) is option for it.